# can not move file using rename

Tags: php, file

I have a tmp folder for holding the temperary uploaded photos and after the user click the save button, the photos would be moved to a new folder.

```
 $ori=$tmp_prefix.$select_array['photo']; //../user_data/tmp_chron/tmp_chronicle/kesongxie/HZi7DkRMvEIa6qc/22.jpg, this is the original files in temparary folder
   $new=$prefix.$select_array['photo']; //../user_data/chron/chronicle/kesongxie/HZi7DkRMvEIa6qc/22.jpg , this is the folder I want to move to
    rename($ori,$new);
```

I cannot move the files to another folder, it gives me a warning without any detail suggested

> warning:rename(../user_data/tmp_chron/tmp_chronicle/kesongxie/HZi7DkRMvEIa6qc/22‌​.jpg,../user_data/chron/chronicle/kesongxie/HZi7DkRMvEIa6qc/22.jpg ) on edit.php line 34

Comment: Can you give us what the warning is?

Comment: warning:rename(../user_data/tmp_chron/tmp_chronicle/kesongxie/HZi7DkRMvEIa6qc/22.jpg,../user_data/chron/chronicle/kesongxie/HZi7DkRMvEIa6qc/22.jpg ) on edit.php line 34

Comment: Does the new file already exist? Are the permissions correct? If it exists, you'll have to unlink first.

Comment: the file is not exist, and the permission's fine, and I have no idea why i receive the warning, what would be the problem? I'm using the right method,right?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it's fine. Can you try var_dump on the variables and see if they are both strings? Or try copy instead of rename and see if that works?

Comment: Is `HZi7DkRMvEIa6qc` a pre-existing/static directory or is it customized per upload/user/whatever and created (`mkdir()`) before the copy/remame?

Comment: @Rasclatt you are right, I mess up, I forgot to create the folder `HZi7DkRMvEIa6qc` , thanks for reminding

Answer (score 0):

Before moving file create parent directory

```
mkdir(dirname($new), 0777, true);
```